# How to delete cookies?

Tags: java, browser, cookies, htmlunit

I want to delete cookies programmatically.

More specifically, I am using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) with Java to automate browser operations. After performing some operations I want to clear cookies so that my subsequent operations make sense. How can I clear cookies through HtmlUnit or through Java or through any other way automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In actual, the cookies in HtmlUnit doesn't get stored on disk until saved programmatically. They remain in the memory. From the memory they gets deleted when the HtmlUnit session expires.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the [CookieManager](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html)?

This class appears to have methods for clearing all cookies or removing them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can user javascript code to expire your cookie using Now to expire it immediately

document.cookie = name + "=; " + Now + "; path=/";

syntax for creating cookie

document.cookie = "name=value; expires=date; path=path;
                   domain=domain; secure";

Comment: Do you mean `document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + Now + "; path=/";`?

Comment: how can I give a command from java to execute javascript code... I mean how can integrate the javascript code with my existing java code

Comment: You have to write it within script tag which gets rendered on client side. Response.write("<script>document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + Now + "; path=/";</script>");